# finding previous group's name in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I want to add a column to my dataframe (with repetitive values) which contains the name of previous group (float and sortable). any idea?

Before:

| Group | value |
| --- | --- |
| 1.1 | value1 |
| 1.1 | value2 |
| 1.1 | value3 |
| 1.1 | value3 |
| 1.2 | value4 |
| 1.2 | value4 |
| 1.2 | value5 |

After:

| Group | value | Previous Group |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1.1 | value1 | Nan |
| 1.1 | value2 | value1 |
| 1.1 | value3 | value2 |
| 1.1 | value3 | value2 |
| 1.2 | value4 | Nan |
| 1.2 | value4 | Nan |
| 1.2 | value5 | Value4 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `groupby` with `shift` which shifts the Group 1 place for each group:

```
df['Previous Group'] = df.groupby("value")['Group'].shift()
```

---

```
print(df)

   Group   value  Previous Group
0    1.1  value1             NaN
1    1.1  value2             NaN
2    1.2  value1             1.1
3    1.2  value2             1.1
```

EDIT:

We can use a helper column with groupby ngroup and then use it as a mapping column and filter out rank = 1:

```
a = df.assign(helper=df.groupby(["Group","value"]).ngroup())
rnk = a.groupby("Group")['helper'].rank(method='dense')
df['Previous Group'] = (a['helper'].sub(1).map(dict(zip(a['helper'],a['value'])))
                         .mask(rnk.eq(1)))
```

---

```
print(df)

   Group   value Previous Group
0    1.1  value1            NaN
1    1.1  value2         value1
2    1.1  value3         value2
3    1.1  value3         value2
4    1.2  value4            NaN
5    1.2  value4            NaN
6    1.2  value5         value4
```

Comment: Thanks @anky for your answer. I've seen this answer elsewhere but the issue with this method is that it is based on index and with repetitive number of Values per group does not work. Let me edit my example so you see it.

Comment: @AmirGhorbani Answer is now updated to address your usecase